# How to connect to service running in XP mode from Windows 7 host?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp-mode

I'm trying to setup a process to run in XP mode and be contacted from the Windows 7 host.

1. I created a loopback in Windows 7 and set my XP mode VPC to use that as it's network adapter.
2. I set a static IP (10.100.0.5/24) on the host and (10.100.0.15/24) on the VPC.  The Gateway for the VPC is 10.100.0.5.
3. I can ping the host from my XP mode PC
4. I cannot ping the VPC from my host.

I need a service to bind to that 10.100.0.15 address on the XP mode VPC and serve data to the Windows 7 host at 10.100.0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the firewall, isn't it?

Answer:  Disable firewall on XP mode VPC.